# Apache server config: how can I disable the certificate/SSL handshake on the WWW version only?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualhost, ssl-certificate

Serving a apache website via https:// => how can I disable the certificate/SSL handshake on the WWW version only?

Hi we use SSL on the https://www version of our website

Now I would like to disable the SSL connection on the https://non-www version of our website

SO the result is:

- https://non-www => SSL handshake
- https://www => no SSL handshake => and htaccess rewrites are executed

**question**: Can this be done?

ps. I am asking because nowadays more websites move to https, not realizing that directing non-www to www traffic (and vice versa) is a little more difficult - because the handshake occurs before the htaccess (rewrite) directives .. the solution is ofcourse an extra certificate ... but a better solution would be to *do find* a solution to just redirect the traffic ...

Appreciate your help

Comment: Yes? I was reading this article and it does cover SSL/virtualhost - I think my question is more related to how can I detect a www-version on a 443 port accept and then if/else to ssl no or ssl yes

Comment: You can't.  If the browser expects to have an SSL conversation you don't get to override that without the browser throwing a hissy fit for the user, and rightly so.  You can choose the flavour of fit (connection refused, SSL negotiation error, certificate error) but not its existence.

Comment: In other words, the way to do this is to have them on separate IP addresses.

Comment: @JennyD I hear you (and drookie, below), but that still won't do what I believe the OP wants, ie rewrites from `https://sitename` to `http://sitename` without any SSL errors.

Comment: @MadHatter My parser got caught up in "not wanting SSL handshake", I think.

Answer (score -1):

Set up two virtual hosts: the one with www without SSL and the one without www - with both SSL and plain HTTP.

*Update*: @MadHatter is right, you'l need 2 IP addresses to separate http and https.

Comment: I am trying to figure this one out. How would I do this on IP/domain level?

Comment: Easily. It can be done using only one IP - this it what virtualhosts are for.

Comment: But then when people visit `https://www` the IP will still resolve, and they'll connect to port 443, which will have a listener - then get an SSL certificate error, surely.

Comment: I agree. I changed the answer.

Comment: That still won't do what the OP asks, ie rewrites.  All you'll get is a "connection refused" error because there won't be a port-443 listener on the `www` IP address, no?

Comment: it's impossible to ask what he wants exactly, because http on a https:// scheme isn't that trivial.

Comment: It's easy to *ask* what he wants, but I agree it's impossible to *satisfy* it; not *not trivial*, but impossible.

Comment: yeah, I mistyped :) and comments cannot be edited after 5 minutes, so now it does look like I really embarass myself. :P